# get struct string in log file

Tags: go, logging

I have a script to print the same log like:

```
type Country stuct{
  cityName string
}

var c Country
```

and I

```
var logger = logrus.New()
logger.Debug(c)
```

but in the log file, it looks like:

```
country_name:\"\\347\\276\\216\\345\\233\\275\"
```

I want to know what `\\347\\276\\216\\345\\233\\275\`  means and how to read the true meanwhile my script read the log file.

Comment: What is `logger` in the posted code?  The string `"\347\276\216\345\233\275\"` contains the octal escapes for `"美国"`.

Comment: var logger = logrus.New()

Answer (score 3):

The default logrus [formatter](https://godoc.org/github.com/sirupsen/logrus#Formatter) writes [JSON with ASCII](https://github.com/sirupsen/logrus/blob/master/README.md) encoding. You need to implement your own formatter and use UTF-8. See [Logger.SetFormatter](https://godoc.org/github.com/sirupsen/logrus#SetFormatter).

As I looked into the source code I didn't see any setting that can be set to change the encoding.

Answer (score 0):

```
func convertOctonaryUtf8(in string) string {
    s := []byte(in)
    reg := regexp.MustCompile(`\\[0-7]{3}`)

    out := reg.ReplaceAllFunc(s,
        func(b []byte) []byte {
            i, _ := strconv.ParseInt(string(b[1:]), 8, 0)
            return []byte{byte(i)}
        })
    return string(out)
}
```

the func get the "\347\276\216\345\233\275\" mean